# How update date value from tstamp column

Tags: sql

How update date value like dd-mm-yy formate from
Current tstamp column

I use below query it throw error

```
Update pallet_dtl
    set fifo_date = to_date(create_tstamp, 'dd-mm-yy')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Date values are stored using an internal format.  You should not be storing them as date.

Comment: What is the error then?

Comment: Error thrown as Missing equal sign

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Why are you duplicating information? The date of a timestamp can easily be extracted so there is no need to save a copy of the data

Comment: Orcale SQL developer

Comment: I need correct fifo date column that's why I take date value from cteate_tstamp column